# Receiving an output from shell_exec with non-standard characters

Tags: python, php, utf-8, shell-exec, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to get the result of a Python program executed through PHP, which passes in the parameter of coordinates, and prints the address at those coordinates.

Eg, when the coordinates 46.07018635,3.93749893 - randomly chosen on Google Maps, don't worry I'm not doxxing myself here - are used, I get the address Renaison, Roanne, Loire, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Metropolitan France, 42370, France. This code works perfectly for coordinates whose address is in English, but when a character like ô appears, when $output is echoed, it shows as a �.

The code for executing the python is:

```
$code = 'python ./reverseGeoloc.py ' . $lat . ',' . $long;
$command = escapeshellcmd($code);
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

And the Python itself is:

```
import sys
coords = sys.argv[1]

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_request")
location = geolocator.reverse(coords, language='en')

print(location.address)
```

So, echoing $output with these coordinates gives:
`Boucherie Charcuterie, Rue du Commerce, Les �tangs-Nord, Chazelles, Renaison, Roanne, Loire, Auvergne-Rh�ne-Alpes, Metropolitan France, 42370, France`.

This does print correctly if ran in isolation in the terminal, giving `Renaison, Roanne, Loire, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Metropolitan France, 42370, France` as expected.

I have tried literally everything I could find Googling, but so far nothing has worked!

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: you need to run it in a different terminal that supports  those characters ...

Comment: Python should run in a UTF-8 locale, so either you specify the environment in PHP, or you set the PHP environment to use a UTF-8 locale. Are you in Windows, right? If you exchange data with files, it is much easier (you have more control, but it is slightly slower). just print the path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found my answer with a long time with experimenting in case anyone ever comes across the same problem. I actually had to use
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');`
at the very beginning of the file rather than using utf-8, and then it was able to correctly interface with the shell exec.